# wxWidgets - wxImage constructor causes page faults

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm using wxWidgets to display a live camera feed.

The following code snippet is part of my OnPaint event:

```
wxBufferedPaintDC dc(picturePanel);
wxMemoryDC mdc;

wxImage img = wxImage(RES_X, RES_Y, image_buffer, true);
wxBitmap bmp(img);
mdc.SelectObject(bmp);
dc.StretchBlit(0,0,940,940,&mdc,0,0,RES_X,RES_Y);
mdc.SelectObject(wxNullBitmap);
```

"image_buffer" is an unsigned char array filled by the camera.
My code works as expected, but I noticed that "wxImage img = wxImage(RES_X, RES_Y, image_buffer, true)" causes a few million page faults after just a couple of minutes. I have no idea how to avoid this problem. Do you think it's something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `static_data = true` in `wxImage` ctor you must guarantee that the image buffer remains valid for as long as the image object exists. The most likely explanation is that it isn't, but it's impossible to be sure because you don't show, or at least tell us anything about, any code allocating or freeing it.

Your last question is very easy to answer however: yes, you should be very concerned about having a fatal bug in your program and you must fix it.

Comment: Hi VZ. Memory for the image buffer is allocated once at program startup and deallocated at program shutdown. Still, I have to use static_data = true, otherwise the program will crash (as expected). There are no memory leaks, just lots of page faults.

Comment: Tell your debugger to stop at first chance exceptions (I assume you use MSW) and check where do they happen, it's really impossible to say more with the information given so far.